# WPF-Property set order in XAML and UserControl custom base class

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, user-controls

Problem is with property init/setting. Problem occurs in UserControl which derives from base class (in which areproperties defined). UserControl consists of one textbox and some business logic defined in base class.

VariableName property in setter calls method which uses VariableType property from same base class.

Problem occures when VariableName is defined first in XAML. I must ensure that VariableType gets value before VariableName.

```
public Enums.Types VariableType
{
    get
    {
        return _variableType;
    }
    set
    {
        _variableType = value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_variableName) && Type == null)
            SetType();
    }
}
public string VariableName
{
    get { return _variableName; }
    set
    {
        _variableName = value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_variableName) && Type == null)
            SetType();
    }
}
private void SetType()
{
    if (Vars == null)
        PopulateVars();
    if (VariableType != Enums.Types.Default)
    {
        Type = Types.SetOveridenType(VariableType);
    }

}
```

And XAML:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestShell"
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Controls.Controls;assembly=Controls" x:Class="TestShell.MainWindow"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Controls:Numeric HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="111" VariableName="SomeName" VariableType="Int16"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I must ensure that VariableType gets value before VariableName.

I think you're assuming the value must always be set first. There are some cases in which you want to stop this operation if value is invalid. Might I suggest adding an additional check in set implementation of `VariableName`?

That is to say, instead of performing set right away, you check to see if `VariableType` has been set yet. If so, set `VariableName`, then do your stuff. Otherwise, value remains unchanged. I've noticed when this happens and the data is bound to a TextBox, the TextBox becomes outlined in red until a valid value is set.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
public string VariableName
{
    get { return _variableName; }
    set
    {
        //I put both conditions here because I forgot, which is 
        //the correct way for checking if an enum value is null,
        //though, my gut's telling me it's the first you'll want 
        //to stick with.
        if (VariableType == default(Enums.Types) || VariableType == null)
            return;
        //VariableType is definitely not null so it's okay to do stuff.
        _variableName = value;
    }
}
```

Tbh, your code was relatively difficult to follow as you are first setting the type on the UserControl and then attempting to set it again when either `VariableType` or `VariableName` changes, but only if the value is null.

Any particular reason why `VariableType` has to initially be null? I always ensure my enums have a default enum value so I never have to check if the value is null, just if it's of the default type (which you do in `SetType`, but only after checking if it's null).

Without knowing the business logic, it'd be difficult to provide any further suggestions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It's like this. VariableType is non nullable enum, and value is always default at the start.
Type on the other hand is of type Type :). 
User of control can change variable type through enum in design time or value is set dynamically in runtime.

Problem is when VariableName is set before enum VariableType, because then I have false Default value, instead for example Int32.

Comment: Anyway I solved this by setting Type in method that initializes control. So I'm sure all props are initialized.